# Requests from facebookexternalhit have truncated query string

Tags: facebook, bots

My server is getting requsts with user-agent "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)". Some of these requests have truncated query strings.

I've been able to recreate the problem by posting the following url to a private facebook group. It seems to try to create a thumbnail, but is unable to.

> https://example.com/blob/?blobId=547c67b0-1400-4a95-b49f-c8c5054f03ae&expiry=&signature=e65L4ieYRPK0k9uVvSYgkvCYiWAAOZHTIJ1jzh2u%2BGziioeBjSHuR6hYfGZ0xR4PHdNrJmai6frpRirJCbRrUOlCmMS1VqHMWBQs8oAChB0S57VqOdz7GDlYgckOZ%2B1oGk6N65A%2Fr1%2BrTwpw%2F0kYuhEwtKgjPOiMisJXbCs%2Bphd82WHHrIwmIgd%2BT6M8J0iomUSBSkHif3IpQ5fHBj%2F%2ByyjNQmRNMlmodbjsLmL9uY2xk9cnpZManv5JgKc0D30DzSW5rkpxLUF%2B%2F8FnPayk%2Bbur1pPEZPJ7bBxPocjbDXW%2BHm43P%2FDtqZNR5Bbg%2FrHemf6Y6tuVQlTLfp3YzPXSIw%3D%3D

The reason the request fails is that facebook truncates the query string like this:

> https://example.com/blob/?blobId=547c67b0-1400-4a95-b49f-c8c5054f03ae&expiry&signature=e65L4ieYRPK0k9uVvSYgkvCYiWAAOZHTIJ1jzh2u%2BGziioeBjSHuR6hYfGZ0xR4PHdNrJmai6frpRirJCbRrUOlCmMS1VqHMWBQs8oAChB0S57VqOdz7GDlYgckOZ%2B1oGk6N65A%2Fr1%2BrTwpw%2F0kYuhEwtKgjPOiMisJXbCs%2Bphd82WHHrIwmIgd%2BT6M8J0iomUSBSkHif3IpQ5fHBj

Why does facebook do this? Is it about url length? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you specifying a `og:url` or canonical URL in the output this URL returns?

Comment: @CBroe the output of a url is a pdf document.